# Solution for the URL Alias and question marks issue in drupal 7

Tags: url, drupal-7

I am working in drupal 7 for developing site. I am using webform for creating a contact us form. After submitting the from successfully, the page is redirected to a confirmation page where the url is http://www.somesite.com/node/11/done?sid=3. I want this particular url as http://www.somesite.com/thankyou.

I tried to set the url alias for **node/11/done?sid=%** as **thankyou**. But unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Can anybody suggest a solution for this..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying the URL alias for that node won't change? Can you change others?

Comment: No.. It won't change by using url alias. But I got a solution for it. I used form_alter of the webform and created a custom function for submit in which I changed the url of submission page.